# Google Cloud virtual instance: Chrome remote desktop indicates remote computer is offline, however Google Cloud Platform shows instance is running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a virtual machine in Google Cloud. I have installed the default Debian OS, and configured the desktop environment for remote connection, as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine

I have been able to connect to the instance via Chrome Remote Desktop, however periodically I have the problem that the Remote Desktop says the vm instance is online, however if I try to connect to it I get:

[image]

Looking at the Google Cloud console, the instance is clearly running. Normally if I restart the instance the problem is solved, however I have processes running on the instance that I do not want to stop.

UPDATE:

Following the advice from Serhii Rohoza I ran

`sudo systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop`

The status looked normal, listing:

`Active: active (exited) since...`

I then ran

`sudo systemctl restart chrome-remote-desktop`

and this solved the problem, I could log into remote desktop again, but it seemed the VM instance had restarted, which is a big problem since I am running processes on it that should not shut down. I guess this is a problem to send to Google Cloud Services support.

UPDATE 2:

I'm still running into this problem. I normally have a Jupyter Notebook running on the VM - this Notebook must keep running. When I saw the message saying that the remote computer is offline, I logged in via ssh and checked if the Jupyter Notebook is running:

`jupyter notebook list`

This returned:

`http://localhost:8888/?token=9110bf40789971b5e252a272e9497039b4f3b45e506348df :: /home/qgenixtech`

So the Notebook was running. I then ran:

`sudo systemctl restart chrome-remote-desktop`

and after that again:

`jupyter notebook list`

and then it shows no Notebooks running. So the restart command closed down the Notebook (and also all other open windows on the desktop).

UPDATE 3:

I spoke to a support technician at Google. The problem is on the Remote Desktop side, not the virtual machine. According to the technician this is a known problem, by he didn't have a solution for it. He referred me to these two links from Google Support:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10213547?hl=en

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3333421?hl=en

The next option for me is to look at something like [X2go](http://wiki.x2go.org)

Comment: Have you tried to follow [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#troubleshooting) and check the status of the Chrome Remote Desktop service with command `sudo systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop` and check log messages at `/tmp/chrome_remote_desktop_DATE_TIME_*` as well?

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if my instructions were helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve your issue** you should follow documentation [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#troubleshooting) and check  status of the Chrome Remote Desktop service with command:

```
 sudo systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop
```

and check log messages at `/tmp/chrome_remote_desktop_DATE_TIME_*`.

**To investigate why your VM instance was restarted** you should look for some clues at the logs:

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM` -> find section **`Logs`** -> click on `Stackdriver Logging`. More information you can find in the documentation [Viewing logs (Classic)](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)
2. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM` -> find section **`Logs`** -> click on `Serial port 1 (console)`. More information in the documentation [Viewing Serial Port Output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output)

You can contact with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) as well.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Setting instance availability policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options).

Answer (score 0):

same issue. when checking logs i see:

```
2021-01-05 14:29:38,319:INFO:Starting Xvfb on display :20
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":20".
2021-01-05 14:29:40,837:INFO:X server is active.
```

restarting service or even VM doesn't work.

i need to delete connection on "client" and re-auth with /headless link

Comment: Do you consider this a solution to the problem? Or is it more of a description of a variant of the problem, which you need help with?

Comment: the code is about an unsolved problem.
my workaround is delete connection and re-auth but it's not a great workaround since the VM auto-disconnects when you logout

Comment: Does your post provide a solution to the problem described at the top of this page? If yes, please rephrase to make that more obvious. If not please delete this post, because only answer to the question are accepted here.